# flask-openapi3 - How to access parsed Pydantic model from an error_handler?

Tags: python, flask

Using the great flask-openapi3 https://luolingchun.github.io/flask-openapi3/v2.x/

Is there a way to access, the `body` parameter of an endpoint globally? From an error handler for example.

I'm trying to log the input payload when an error occurs, but re-parsing the input is far from efficient